# How to access tag's attribute value with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup and requests for web scraping. I know how to extract attribute between tags, but if what I want is the number `'4.31'` below in a tag, any idea how to get it?

```py
<div class="starRating" title="4.31">
<svg
 ...
</svg>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```py
soup.find('div',{'class':'starRating'})
soup.find('title')
```

which returns nothing, so the number is basically the tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the attribute `title` value like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = """
<html>
<div class="starRating" title="4.31">
<svg>
</svg>
</div>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'starRating'})['title'])
```

Outputs:

```
4.31
```

See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes
`

> A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag `<b id="boldest">` has an attribute “id” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda to query elements with the matching `title` attribute, then use the `["title"]` key to extract the data you want:

```
>>> soup.find(lambda x: x.name == "div" and "title" in x.attrs)["title"]
'4.31'
```

Or use a CSS selector:

```
>>> soup.select_one("div[title]")
<div class="starRating" title="4.31"></div>
```

Even easier, use the target attribute as a kwarg:

```
>>> soup.find("div", title=True)
<div class="starRating" title="4.31"></div>
```

Attempting to pull the `title` attribute out of an element that doesn't have it will raise a `KeyError`, so it's worth filtering ahead of time. Use `find_all` or `select` if you'd like an iterable of multiple results.